# Redirecting to Login page to whatever link i click on

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

Whatever the link I click.I am getting redirected to login page only.

I have tried changing urls.py order and redirecting the urls but I want signup should redirect to the signup page and login should redirect it to the login page.but when i am clicking on any link it is redirecting to login page only.

```
urls.py
------

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from app import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import url, include

app_name = "App"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^Login/', views.Login,name='Login'),
    url(r'^Logout/', views.Logout,name='Logout'),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('App/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]

models.py:
---------
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
     fname = models.CharField('fname', max_length=120)
     lname = models.CharField('lname',max_length=120)
     username = models.CharField('username',max_length = 60,unique=True)
     password = models.CharField('password',max_length=120,default='pavi@2789')

     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.fname

     class Meta:
          # managed = False
          db_table = "user"

view.py:
---------
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout,login
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
from .models import Event
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError
from .context_processors import include_login_form
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import login_form
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError



# Create your views here.
# @login_required(login_url="Login/")

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            password = userObj['password']
            fname = userObj['fname']
            lname = userObj['lname']
            print (username,password,fname,lname)
            if(len(password)<8):
                raise ValidationError("This password length should be minimum 8 characters ")
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
                p = Event(fname=fname, lname=lname, username=username, password=password)
                p.save()
                #return HttpResponseRedirect('Login.html')
                return redirect('/Login/')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like a username with that username or password already exists')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form' : form})


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def Login(request):
    form = login_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        print (username,password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print('user is', user)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            print ('entered loop')
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/home/')
        else:
            print ("username and password are incorrect ")
    else:
        form = login_form()
    return render(request, 'Login.html', {'form': form})

def Logout(request):
    logout(request)

settings.py:
-----------

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
#
LOGIN_URL = 'Login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'Logout'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=App'
        },
        'NAME': 'DBName',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXX',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'App\templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


forms.py:
--------
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Event
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout,login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(required=True,label='FirstName',max_length=32)

    lname = forms.CharField(required=True,label='LastName',max_length=32)

    username = forms.CharField(required = True,label = 'Username',max_length = 32)

    password = forms.CharField(required = True,label = 'Password',max_length = 32)


class login_form(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


index.html;
----------
<!-- App/templates/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MYProject!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Project!</h1>
    <a href="/"><br>Signup</br> </a>
    <a href="/">Login</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

signup should redirect to sign up page and login should redirect to login page.

Comment: do you have login.html are you rendering forms properly there?

Comment: I have login.html {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>username or password not correct</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand how you expect this to work:

```
<a href="/"><br>Signup</br> </a>
<a href="/">Login</a>
```

You have two links there, and you've hard-coded the destination of both links as "/", which is the index page. If you want them to go to the actual pages, you need to put the actual links in. You can use the `{% url %}` tag to avoid hard-coding the paths.

```
<a href="{% url "signup" %}"><br>Signup</br> </a>
<a href="{% url "Login" %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: I have tried giving url path in index.html but as it doesnt work for me i have used "/"

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You can't use `/` because that doesn't point to login or signup.

Comment: but when i am opening any link it is getting redirected to login page only.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Daneil Roseman's Answer(I think addresses the actual problem of the question), I think your problem is with the urlpattern regex. Please update them like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', views.index,name='index'),  # using $ to strict match pattern
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.Login,name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.Logout,name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^app/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),  # pattern for accepting any pattern

]
```